# derivatives with respect to outward pointing normal

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I'm a bit curious about applying the divergence theorem (or a particular case of it, not sure).  Let's say we have a twice continuously differentiable function $u$ in some open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$.  Then for some $r>0$, we have

$\int_{B(0,r)}\Delta u dx=\int_{\partial B(0,r)}\frac{\partial u}{\partial\nu}dS$, where $\nu$ is the outward pointing normal of the ball of radius $r$.  Can I further imply that $\int_{\partial B(0,r)}\frac{\partial u}{\partial\nu}dS=\int_{\partial B(0,1)}u_{r}(ry)dS(y)=[\int_{\partial B(0,1)}u(ry)dS(y)]_{r}$.  This seems to be a trick my teacher did in class and I'm not quite understanding the technicalities of it, but I think I see what he wants to do.  It looks like he wants to rescale the ball to the unit ball, and then $r$ will be a unit vector and the exterior normal, and then pull the derivative outside of the integral.  My only issue is that the integrand still depends on r, and I'm not sure if you even need to rescale the unit ball. Does $\nu$ even need to be a unit vector?  For example could I just say that $\int_{\partial B(0,r)}\frac{\partial u}{\partial\nu}dS=\int_{\partial B(0,r)}u_{r}dS=[\int_{\partial B(0,r)}udS]_r$, which still bothers me since the bounds depend on r.  Could someone help me clarify where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Why should the value of the integral not depend on $r$?

Comment: It certainly does, so I'm not sure if I can pull the derivative off of u outside of the integral, since the integral depends on r.